# Change a java class

Tags: java, performance, file, biginteger

I have found a potentially faster implementation of the BigInteger class. Anyone can tell me how can I change the original BigInteger class found in java.math with this one please.
Thanks in advance.

Actually, it is not my implementation, it is presented in http://www.mail-archive.com/core-libs-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg01746.html,.
Every improvement is their work not mine, I am just trying to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'change'? Do you want to subclass it or make a different class with the same name as BigInteger?

Comment: use `-Xbootclasspath/p` option of java; btw make sure your class has *no final fields*, it's counter productive for classes that create tons of very short lived objects.

Comment: @bestsss: do you have some link with an explanation for this assertion (final does bad things)?

Comment: @Paŭlo, it doesn't do bad things but issues a memory barrier. So if you can intense calculations in a loop, it's totally useless. I can look for some link but I guess you can trust me.

Comment: @Paŭlo, Remembered a link but it's a video :D It's an interview w/ the hotspot architect: http://www.infoq.com/interviews/click-gc-azul around the 20th minute or jump *I think in your blog you’ve looked at a few alternative languages like JRuby and Clojure. What were the problems that you found? What problems do they have with the current JVMs?*

Comment: *Actually, it is not my implementation, it is presented in http://www.mail-archive.com/core-libs-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg01746.html* definitely follow the advice I offered, add the class into -Xbootclasspath/p and it's all done.

Comment: @bestsss: it is not about "trust you", but "I want to know the details". Thanks for the links. (I think for really big BigInteger like classes it would matter less than for a one-int-class like Integer, but we should not discuss this here.)

Comment: @Paŭlo, BigInteger is not much bigger than Integer (esp. for smaller values). As long as it stays in the cpu cache the performance would be a lot better. The idea is avoiding final fields during massive allocation/calculation loops.

Comment: @bestsss: in principle the JIT should be able to optimize this barrier away if there is no inter-thread interaction. But for current VMs it may be relevant if you are doing such things.

Comment: @Paŭlo, in theory - yes, but w/o intrinsics the necessary methods to inline are quite long for the JIT to be able to use escape analysis, use different c-tor code and effectively optimize it away. Possible, but it needs really strong optimization. The discussion turned too theoretical, but I hope the information was useful.

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Simply include the jar file (or class file, or source) of the potentially faster implementation, and instantiate it instead.

Comment: I would discourage the override option, a single class target makes much better JIT code. 2 call targets are still acceptable, though. However a lot of existing code will never see any improvement. Imo, if you are using for solely your own needs, keep it custom and be done with.

Comment: @bestsss: in the area where those optimizations make sense (~500 digit decimal numbers), I'd guess that the method call overhead is not the most important aspect of performance.

Comment: @Joachim, sure, it's not (unless there is a internal call to some other public/overriden methods in a loop). Aside that, the BigInteger subclass will take more than a single cache-line (due to inherited fields) and that would be unpleasant. Each allocation will require 2new cache-lines instead of one. If I try to optimize BigInteger my goal would be to spawn the data into as little memory as possible. Of course the more digits/precision you add, the lesser effect of the constant memory the class takes.

Comment: @Joachim ...actually that reminds me: a great possible optimization would be using a simple long when the value fits into. BigInteger is very often used even w/o so BIG values. (BigDecimal does it internally and can be faster than BigInteger)

Comment: actually overriding could be a worse idea than I initially anticipated. It will require calling the superclass c-tor `BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)` is probably acceptable but still wasteful one. Worse comes that w/ the fact that all methods accept BigInteger. The passed value can be indeed a vanila BigInteger. Since there is no way to access the package private fields (baring putting the class in java.math, itself), the passed BigInteger must be exported (toByteArray). The overall solution will be hard to code and looks like bug-patch than performance gain one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to use your "java.math.BigInteger" instead of the JVMs version.

I don't think you want to do this because it would require you to update all the JDK/JRE that use your application.  A better solution is to your "YourBigInteger" instead of the BigInteger in your application.

You could also be asking how to get it looked at by the masses to be included in a JDK/JRE.  In that case, I would say start with OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

There's almost no reason why you would want to exchange BigInteger in Java with yours, unless you're absolutely sure that it's not only faster in ALL relevant cases, but is also safe to use for all programs that would have depended on the original BigInteger, and doesn't conflict with Java internally (at a level even developers may not notice).

If all of the above are true, then you really submit your class to Oracle, because I'm sure they're looking for more efficient implementations constantly and you could really help us all out by releasing your faster BigInteger class in Java 7 or 8, perhaps.

But since you say you've only "potentially" found a faster implementation, what you really want is a subclass:

```
public class FastBigInteger extends java.math.BigInteger
{
```

and override all the methods you think can be sped up

```
    public BigInteger divide(BigInteger val)
    {
        //your faster implementation goes here
    }
}
```

and then you can start testing this class against java's class, timing the running time of each for many test cases, and presenting the findings to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Java gets all of its built-in classes from rt.jar.  You could replace the BigInteger class with another implementation within that JAR.

Of course, I wouldn't recommend it.  Extending BigInteger would in almost all situations be a much better idea.  But it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override classes shipped in the JRE through the Java "endorsed" mechanism:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

However, I completely agree with the above - if possible you should be simply using your class instead of replacing BigInteger: this method doesn't require changing the JRE, and there's no risk of breaking some other package that depends on BigInteger.

However, if you have a 3rd-party package that uses BigInteger, and you want to switch the implementation under it for some reason (think long about this), the endorsed mechanism may be what you need.